# My own shopping basket

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to add my `Item` to `Basket` ?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Basket(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_basket', verbose_name='Owner')
    name = models.CharField("Basket name", max_length=120)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', blank=True, null=True)
```

My try:

```
def add_item_to_basket(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = BasketForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            items = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
            .........?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_basket.items.add(your_item)
```

Or give a look here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships